# retrieve a list view item created in one class to main form

Tags: c#

The goal of my program is to simulate the rolling of two dice, the display the random numbers generated and their sum in a three column list view.

I am having trouble getting the `ListViewItem` generated in my Roller class back to my Form1 so I can add it to my list view.

I have tried adding the `ListViewItem` directly to the list view from the roller class, but I can not figure out how to access the list view from my roller class.

Here is my code from my form1 that calls my roller class.

```
private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Roller roller1 = new Roller();
    lvRollResults.Items.Add(Roller.ListViewItem(item));
}
```

Here is the code for my Roller class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class Roller
    {
        ListViewItem item;

        private void randomizer()
        {

            int counter = 100; 
            int temp1;
            int temp2;
            int sum;

            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
            {

            temp1 = rand.Next(1, 7);//set temp1 to a random number betwen 1&6

            temp2 = rand.Next(1, 7);//set temp2 to a random number between 1&6

            sum = temp1 + temp2;//set sum equal to temp1+temp2

            String one = Convert.ToString(temp1);
            String two = Convert.ToString(temp2);
            String three = Convert.ToString(sum);



            item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { one, two, three });

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I have read my text books, searched the internet and I cannot for the life of me figure this out. I have a hunch it is something to do with my method constructor, but every time I try to change it I end up with more errors.

=======================================Update==========================================

I could not get any of the suggestions to work. To solve my problem I just put the all the code from my Roller class in Form1 under the Roll_Click function.

I appreciate all the help offered.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `list` `static` in `form1` so you can access it from outside of the class as well. Now for your problem you all have to do is this:

**1.** Make your `lvRollResults` static, code:

```
static ListView lvRollResults
```

**2.** Now in the `Roller` class you can directly put the values into the   `lvRollResults`. code for `Roller` class:

```
Form1.lvRollResults.Items.Add(item); //put this code after the 'for loop' in randomizer' method
```

**3.** Code for your `btnRoll_Click` method:

```
Roller roller1 = new Roller();  
roller1.randomizer();
```

Edit:

To make your list box static do this:
In your `form1`, create listbox by coding like `static ListBox lvRollResults`
set its dimensions in the constructor of `form1`.

Comment: Where would I enter code to make my lvRollResults static? I have tried altering the         private void lvRollResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this based on the code you have shown is:-

Your listviewitem needs to be public

```
  public ListViewItem item;
```

then you can get it using

```
  Roller roller1 = new Roller();
   lvRollResults.Items.Add(roller1.item);
```

Provided you invoke `randomizer()` method in your `Roller` class constructor.

```
public Roller()
{
   randomizer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in `Roller` calling Randomizer...
Or, change `void randomize()` by `Roller()`

And in `Form1`, use `roller1.item` instead of `Roller.item`

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to make your Randomizer method `public` instead of `private` and instead of `void` return it as `ListviewItem`.

```
  public ListviewItem Randomizer()
```

And then your `Randomizer` will return the `ListViewItem`.

```
  return item;
```

So, in your button click it would be like this.

```
  private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Roller roller1 = new Roller();
    lvRollResults.Items.Add(roller1.Randomizer());
   }
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error that lvRollResults does not exist in the context, in the btnRoll_Click code.

Comment: @BrianDawson lvlRollResults is from your own code that I just copied and therefore you should know if it really exist. Try to check the name of your ListView if its lvRollResults and change it to that name. Or try to check if you have a listview at all in which I doubt if you don't have one. Most likely you have one and it just a matter of wrong name like a different spelling for example.